# Difference between DDR3 RAM PC3-10600S vs PC3-10600

Tags: memory, ddr3

I am trying to upgrade my RAM of my HP G62-b51SE and found that the stock RAM type is DDR3 PC3-10600S.

I am trying to find the difference between that (PC3-10600S) and PC3-10600.

Comment: This is my stock ram and i cant find information on ram type pc3-10600S : http://tinypic.com/r/kx6qo/6

Comment: maybe it is meant to mean plural.

Comment: Maybe the S refers to Stock.

Comment: Where did you see "pc3-10600s" exactly?

Answer (score 7):

Following on from [Grace's answer](https://superuser.com/questions/520763/difference-between-ddr3-ram-pc3-10600s-vs-pc3-10600#answer-1067466), this link [What's the difference between DDR3 1333 MHz PC3-10600S and DDR3 1333 MHz PC3-10600](https://discussions.apple.com/message/29386537#29386537) states:

> To answer you actual question correctly.  The "S" as in DDR3 10600S
>   for example stands for SO-DIMM which is the size of RAM for Laptops.
>   If you had desktop memory the same RAM would say DDR3 10600. Crucial
>   and other companies have a way of not listing the RAM speed with the
>   "S' because in the title of the RAM you are purchasing it says
>   "SO-DIM'  but when you get your RAM it will have the "S" on it if you
>   are buying for a laptop.

Answer (score 5):

S stands for SODIMM, meaning the RAM is for laptop.

Comment: +1 - For the _actual_ correct answer..! However, if you could edit your link to provide some backup to your statement (a link and a summary of that link), that would be great.

Answer (score -2):

Google searches for [598859-001](http://www.google.com/search?q=598859-001) and [598856-001](http://www.google.com/search?q=598855-001) as shown as the replacement parts in your picture result in memory of type pc3-10600. I think its just a confusing label on your modules.

Comment: Even if 10600S is the actual stock type, I'm guessing there is no practical difference.

Comment: PC3-10600S would usually indicate registered, synchronous memory. See, for example, [here](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/479633429036823136/) or [here](http://www.amazon.com/HYNIX-Laptop-Memory-HMT325S6BFR8C-H9-PC3-10600S/dp/1254875778).